# Remove menubar from Electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

How do I remove this menu-bar from my electron apps:

[image: menu-bar]

Also it says "Hello World"(is this because I downloaded electron pre-built, and will go away once I package the application?). I didn't code these into the html, so I don't know how to get it out!-

Answer (score 344, accepted):

You can use `w.setMenu(null)` or set `frame: false` (this also removes buttons for close, minimize and maximize options) on your window. See [setMenu()](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetmenumenu-linux-windows) or [BrowserWindow()](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/). Also check this [thread](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1415)

---

Electron now has [`win.removeMenu()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winremovemenu-linux-windows) (*added in v5.0.0*), to remove application menus instead of using `win.setMenu(null)`.

---

Electron 7.1.x seems to have a bug where `win.removeMenu()` doesn't work. The only workaround is to use `Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)`, however, this will disable all the menu shortcuts like <kbd>F11</kbd> for toggling fullscreen etc.

---

In new versions of Electron, you can set `autoHideMenuBar: true` while creating browserWindow, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> will show the menu bar again.

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  autoHideMenuBar: true,
})
```

Comment: fwiw `removeMenu()` is Linux & Windows only

Comment: what about in windows opened by window.open() in an already open window having a menu?

Comment: Electron 7.1.1 has an issue where `setMenu` and `removeMenu` don't work anymore [link](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21088)

Comment: Neither the original or the edit solutions work.  This should no longer be the answer.

Comment: I just created a new app and tried `win.removeMenu()`. It worked.

Answer (score 109):

Use this:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 640, height: 360})
mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false)
```

Reference: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1415

I tried `mainWindow.setMenu(null)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: I tried `mainWindow.setMenu(null)` with electron 5.0.2 and it did not work fir me as well. Not sure why I see advise to use it everywhere, and was wandering if I am the only one that is doing something incorrectly. Your advice of using `setMenuBarVisibility` ,though removes the visibility of the menu bar, does not remove it completely. It can be brought back by pressing the `Alt` key.

Comment: FWIW: With Election 6.0.X neither `.setMenu(null)` or `.removeMenu()` worked for me. `.setMenuBarVisibility(false)` removes the menu bar and the `Alt` key only works if `.setAutoHideMenuBar(true)` is run.

Comment: +1, in Arch Linux, `setMenu(null)` didn't work, but `setMenuBarVisibility(false)` works as expected (the bar **cannot** be brought back by pressing the `alt` key as @Artium mentioned).

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. The answer that is marked correct does not work on Ubuntu 18.04, Electron v6.0.9

Comment: This is the best answer because keyboard shortcuts in the hidden menu will still work. So you can use the default macOS menu with accelerators and everything, and they'll work on Windows without the ugly Windows menu.

Comment: Currently, only `mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false)` worked on Ubuntu.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani even on archlinux setMenu(null) works

Answer (score 42):

For Electron 7.1.1, you can use this:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron')
Menu.setApplicationMenu(false)
```

Comment: Update edit for me: `Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)` worked in `7.1.2`
Other solutions did not work for me!

Comment: It also works on 7.1.4. Please update right answer to make sure everyone with this problem will be able to reach the solution.

Comment: Works for me in electron 7.1.6

Comment: Works for me in electron 7.19
This should definitely be updated as the correct answer

Comment: This answer worked for me for Electron v10.1.1. Thanks :)

Answer (score 25):

The menu **can be hidden** or **auto-hidden** (like in **Slack** or **VS Code** - you can **press Alt to show/hide** the menu).

## Relevant methods:

---- [win.setMenu(menu)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetmenumenu-linux-windows) - Sets the menu as the window’s menu bar,
   setting it to null will remove the menu bar. (**This will remove the menu completly**)

```
mainWindow.setMenu(null)
```

---- [win.setAutoHideMenuBar(hide)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetmenumenu-linux-windows) - Sets whether the window menu bar 
   should hide itself automatically. **Once set** the menu bar **will only

   show** when users **press** the single **Alt key**.

```
mainWindow.setAutoHideMenuBar(true)
```

Source: https://github.com/Automattic/simplenote-electron/issues/293

**There is also the method for making a frameless window as shown bellow:**

(no close button no anything. Can be what we want (better design))

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, frame: false })
win.show()
```

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winremovemenu-linux-windows

doc: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window

## Edit: (new)

> `win.removeMenu()` Linux Windows Remove the window's menu bar.

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winremovemenu-linux-windows

Added win.removeMenu() to remove application menus instead of using win.setMenu(null)

That is added from v5 as per:

https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/16570

https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/16657

## Electron v7 bug

For Electron 7.1.1 use `Menu.setApplicationMenu` instead of `win.removeMenu()`

as per this thread:
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16521

And the big note is: you have to call it **before creating the BrowserWindow**! Or it will not work!

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron')

Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);

const browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({/*...*/});
```

## UPDATE (Setting autoHideMenuBar on BrowserWindow construction)

As by @kcpr comment! We can set the property and many on the constructor

That's available on the latest stable version of electron by now which is 8.3!
But too in old versions i checked for v1, v2, v3, v4!
It's there in all versions!

As per this link
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/1-3-x/docs/api/browser-window.md

And for the v8.3
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v8.3.0/docs/api/browser-window.md#new-browserwindowoptions

The doc link
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions

From the doc for the option:

> autoHideMenuBar Boolean (optional) - Auto hide the menu bar unless the Alt key is pressed. Default is false.

Here a snippet to illustrate it:

```js
let browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    autoHideMenuBar: true // <<< here
})
```

Comment: setAutoHideMenuBar is deprecated

Comment: The answer by Edmar below is a better version, latest code for autoHiding the menu

Comment: In Electron 8.2.5 (I suspect that also in previous versions) it's possible to define, that the menu bar should be auto-hidden in `BrowserWindow` constructor like so:
`new BrowserWindow({autoHideMenuBar: true})`.  

And, by the way, thank You for this answer. It seems to me to be probably the most complete one (assuming that the methods still exist and are not deprecated).

Comment: @kcpr Thank you for your answer! I updated the answer to reflect this!

Answer (score 10):

When you package your app the default menu won't be there anymore, if this is bugging you during development then you can call `setMenu(null)` on the browser window as suggested by @TonyVincent.

Answer (score 10):

As of 7.0.0, most of the above solutions no longer work.
`BrowserWindow.setMenu()` has been replaced by `Menu.setApplicationMenu()`, which now changes the menu on all windows. `setMenu()`, `removeMenu()` no longer do anything, Which by the way are still mentioned in the docs.

`setAutoHideMenuBar()` still works, but could be a nuisance if you planned to use Alt as a hotkey modifier. Once menu is visible you have to click away from window (loose focus) to hide menu again.

If your application has more than one window, you can't set/remove menus separately on each window. The only way to remove a menu is to use the frameless window approach. That happens to be what I want in my current application, but not a good solution in all cases.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only thing that works since 7.0! Is there any mention of this in the docs/changelogs/etc?

Comment: There is an issue open in the github project [link](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21088) . Don't know if it was planned deprecation or a bug.

Answer (score 9):

These solutions has bug.
When use solutions at below, windows has delay at closing.

```
Menu.setApplicationMenu(null),
&&
const updateErrorWindow = new BrowserWindow({autoHideMenuBar: true});
```

I used solution at below. This is better for now.

```
const window= new BrowserWindow({...});
window.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
@"electron": "^7.1.1" : 

mainWindow = new browserWindow({ height: 500, width: 800});
//mainWindow.setAutoHideMenuBar(true);
mainWindow.autoHideMenuBar = true;
```

Working as expected without menu in browser.

Comment: (electron) 'setAutoHideMenuBar function' is deprecated and will be removed. Please use 'autoHideMenuBar property' instead.                                                                                                               @"electron": "^7.1.1" : 
mainWindow = new browserWindow({ height: 500, width: 800});   mainWindow.autoHideMenuBar = true;

Answer (score 8):

set autoHideMenuBar to true while creating the browserWindow

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    width: 1200,
    height: 800
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Electron **12.0.6**:

```
    let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        autoHideMenuBar: true
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

2020 Update, the only bl**dy thing that worked for me:

```
Menu.setApplicationMenu(new Menu());
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works as of 2nd december 2020

Answer (score 5):

Following the answer from [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16521#issuecomment-544248413), you must call `Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)` *before* the window is created

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Links to other answers are better suited as comments, rather than answers. This is because you are not actually applying the answer in the linked question to this user's specific scenario.

Answer (score 5):

`setMenu(null);` is the best answer,  `autohidemenu` will display on the start of the application

```
    function createWindow(){
        const win = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 1500,
            height: 800,
            webPreferences:{
                nodeIntergration: true
            }
        });
        win.setMenu(null);
    win.loadFile("index.html");
    }
    app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```

Answer (score 4):

Before this line at main.js:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 900})

mainWindow.setMenu(null) //this will r menu bar
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers here are not valid for newer versions. With the version of 9.0 or upper, `Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);` should work. By the way, `Menu` exported from electron package: `const {Menu} = require('electron');`

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentation @ https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v8.0.0-beta.1/docs/api/menu.md the proper way to do this now since 7.1.2 and I have tested it on 8.0 as well is to :

```
const { app, Menu } = require('electron')

Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)
```

Answer (score 3):

Even if `autoHideMenuBar: true`, you still can toggle menu bar with `Alt` key.

So to hide it completely, use `mainWindow.setMenu(null)`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be

```
 const { Menu } = require('electron');
 const template = [];
 const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
 Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
```