# Electron with top menu when packaged

Tags: windows-10, electron, exe

Electron remains with this top menu when bundled for Windows 10 I'm using:

[image]

To package my project I am using the following package.json command:

```
npm run dist
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.0.12",
    "electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
    "electron-packager": "^14.0.6"
  },
  "build": {
    "target": "NSIS",
    "appId": "your.id",
    "mac": {
      "category": "your.app.category.type"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the way I am creating the window:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  win.loadFile('global.html')
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

When I click on the .exe file after compiling my project, this top menu still appears in the program.

How can I get this top menu off when my project is packaged for .exe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove menubar from Electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091964/remove-menubar-from-electron-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [win.removeMenu()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winremovemenu-linux-windows) function to remove the menu.

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091964/remove-menubar-from-electron-app).