# how do I remove menu bar from electron app

Tags: electron

I know this has been asked but previous answers aren't working. This is my first electron app.

Here is my main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

function createWindow () {
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    win.loadFile('index.html')

    // Open the DevTools.
    //win.webContents.openDevTools()

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    win.on('closed', () => {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        win = null
    })

}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
    win.setMenu(null);
})


// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

I thought `win.setMenu(null);`would remove the menu bar but it does not.  What do I need to do to completely remove this?

--The only think I've found that is sort of close is making the app frameless.

```
  win = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            frame: false,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true
            }
        })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove menubar from Electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091964/remove-menubar-from-electron-app)

Comment: @DanD. none of those answers seem to work in electron 7

Answer (score 0):

For Windows and Linux:

```
require('electron').Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);
```

Refer to https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menusetapplicationmenumenu

Comment: What OS do you run? Your code seems to be suitable only for re-launch app in MacOS. Try to put this line outside the app.on('activate', ...) block.
Also, there is no way to hide upper menu for MacOS.

Comment: The code works when you put it outside the activate event