# How to create new window without menu bar for onlick function (electronJS)

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

I tried this but this gives me a new window with menu bar. I removed main window menu bar using `win.setMenu(null)` in main.js file. but I couldn't find a way to do it in new window ("add items window")
please see the image below to see it clearly

```
onclick="window.open('addNew.html' ,'Add New Item', 'width=900 , height=400 , toolbar=no ,resizable=no')
```

[image: window with menu bar]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove menubar from Electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091964/remove-menubar-from-electron-app)

Comment: No, i removed main window menue bar using "win.setMenu(null)" in main.js file. but i couldn't find a way to do it in new window ("add items window") please find the attached image to see it clearly. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can intercept the new window creation and remove the menu the same way you remove it for your main window.

```
const { app } = require("electron");
app.on("browser-window-created", (e, win) => {
    win.removeMenu();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used 'Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)' insted of 'win.setMenu(null)'. this works for me. thank you.