# How can I hide the menubar from an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron, menubar

I recently started making a desktop app with Electron, and staring at that menu bar that's always there at the top is getting annoying.

So, I went online and scoured the web for a good solution - but most answers I found were either very old, might not be supported in all operating systems, or just weren't what I was looking for. So, here I am, asking a question which will probably be marked a duplicate.

I want to hide the menubar in my app *permanently* - so setting the `autoHideMenuBar` property to `true` won't work, as then the <kbd>alt</kbd> key would still show it.

I want to keep functionality like using <kbd>F11</kbd> to get fullscreen as well.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove menubar from Electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091964/remove-menubar-from-electron-app)

Answer (score 2):

There are normally a few ways to do this, here are some suggestions:

1. Set menu to null when creating the window:

   `const mainWin = new BrowserWindow({menu: null});`
2. Remove menu after window object has been created (Set a blank menu with MacOS):

   `const { Menu } = require('electron');`

   `process.platform === "win32" && mainWin.removeMenu();`

   `process.platform === "darwin" && Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate([]));`
3. Using the Menu module from electron:

   `const { Menu } = require('electron');`

   `Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```js
const { Menu } = require('electron');
Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);
```